# Python: shortest way to compute cartesian power of list

Tags: python, list, product, cartesian

Suppose we have a list `L`. The cartesian product `L x L` could be computed like this:

```
product = [(a,b) for a in L for b in L]
```

How can the cartesian power `L x L x L x ... x L` (n times, for a given n) be computed, in a short and efficient way?

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate. It is not: there is only one list in the OP, whereas the linked question has a list of lists, which is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
product = itertools.product(L, repeat=n)
```

where `product` is now a iterable; call `list(product)` if you want to materialize that to a full list:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(3), repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```