# Defining an ndarray in python via a formula

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, initiated as `C=np.zeros([20,20,20,20])`. Then I'm trying to assign some values to C via some formula (`C(x)=(exp(-|x|^2)` in this case). The following code works but is *extremely* slow.

> ```
> it=np.nditer(C, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
> while not it.finished:
>     diff=np.linalg.norm(np.array(it.multi_index))
>     it[0]=np.exp(-diff**2)
>     it.iternext()
> ```

Can this by done in a faster and possibly more pythonish way?

Comment: Judging from your example you have found the `nditer` tutorial page.  At the end it has an example of using `nditer` in Cython code.  That is fast.  But in Python code it isn't faster than other iteration methods.  It's better to avoid iteration entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

**Step #1** Get all combinations corresponding to all indices being calculated with `np.array(it.multi_index)` in the code. On this, one can leverage [`product from itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

**Step #2** Perform the L2 norm calculations across all combinations in a vectorized manner.

**Step #3** Finally do `C(x)=(exp(-|x|^2)` in an elementwise manner.

```
# Get combinations using itertools.product
combs = np.array(list(product(range(N), repeat=4)))

# Perform L2 norm and elementwise exponential calculations to get final o/p 
out = np.exp(-np.sqrt((combs**2).sum(1))**2).reshape(N,N,N,N)
```

Runtime tests and verify output -

```
In [42]: def vectorized_app(N):
    ...:     combs = np.array(list(product(range(N), repeat=4)))
    ...:     return np.exp(-np.sqrt((combs**2).sum(1))**2).reshape(N,N,N,N)
    ...: 
    ...: def original_app(N):
    ...:     C=np.zeros([N,N,N,N])
    ...:     it=np.nditer(C, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
    ...:     while not it.finished:
    ...:         diff_n=np.linalg.norm(np.array(it.multi_index))
    ...:         it[0]=np.exp(-diff_n**2)
    ...:         it.iternext()
    ...:     return C
    ...: 

In [43]: N = 10

In [44]: %timeit original_app(N)
1 loops, best of 3: 288 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit vectorized_app(N)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.63 ms per loop

In [46]: np.allclose(vectorized_app(N),original_app(N))
Out[46]: True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just get the  "product() got an unexpected keyword argument 'repeat'" but maybe it's an old versino of python (?)

Comment: @PeterFranek What's your Python version?

Comment: 2.7.6.. (under Ubuntu)Should I reinstall it?

Comment: @PeterFranek Ok, I am on `2.7.9`. This feature seems like pretty old one, as used here in [`2013 question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14615595/3293881). Could you try reinstalling? I think this `product with repeat` would be quite useful for you anyway!

Comment: Just a last question, is your code really at least twice faster? If yes, I will reinstall :)

Comment: @PeterFranek It's **`33x`** faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you just wan't to apply your operation to the indices of each element?  How about this:

```
x = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(np.indices([20,20,20,20]), axis=0)**2)
```

np.indices is a really slick function.  Also related are mgrid and meshgrid for more complex operations.  In this case, since you have 4 dimensions, it returns an array with shape (4,20,20,20,20).

And pure numpy is a little faster :)

```
In [13]: timeit posted_code()
1 loops, best of 3: 843 ms per loop

In [14]: timeit np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(np.indices([20,20,20,20]), axis=0)**2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.76 ms per loop
```

And it is exactly the same result:

```
In [26]: np.all(C == x)
Out[26]: True
```